# Android WebView questions: alternative to onPageFinished, how to manage cache

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have an Android app that utilizes WebView. We have it set to show a splash page upon app open and then the splash page goes when the page is loaded. This is the relevant code:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new BrowserClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            // Work around for WebView onPageFinished called twice                
if (flag == true) {
                    browser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    splashImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    pageLoader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is, often there is significant delay between when the splash page appears and when it is taken down -- delay that is not attributable to the page loading. (Meaning, the splash page is not being taken away after the page has loaded.) Im guessing this is because onPageFinished is fired when the page has fully loaded, including all scripts, which can sometimes be delayed (e.g. ads).

So, the question is, is there any other way I can detect when the page has fully loaded? Or, even better, is it possible to detect when above-the-fold has loaded (i.e. viewable content without scrolling)?

Second question is related to the way WebView handles caching. Sometimes, I see that WebView is showing stale pages -- pages that have already been updated on my website. How can I force WebView to check / revalidate pages on each page load or back button press so that stale content is not shown? I don't necessarily want to disable WebView caching altogether because there is value in having a cache. I just don't want stale content.

Thanks!